# How to put a border around a tikz figure with tcbox?

Tags: tikz

The following code produces the figure I want but only when I remove the \tcbox. I'd like a border around the figure. What I have done below works with other tikz figures. The problem seems to be with the table data. Can anyone please advise?

```
\begin{figure}
\tcbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=south east,
    xlabel=Variable 1, % label x axis
    ylabel=Variable 2, % label y axis
    ]
    \addplot[
        scatter, only marks,
        scatter/classes={
            a={mark=square*,blue},
            b={mark=triangle*,red}
        }
    ]
    table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
        x    y    label
        0.1  0.35 a
        0.2 0.4 a
        0.25 0.35 a
        0.3 0.4 a
        0.3 0.35 a
        0.4 0.3 a
        0.45 0.3 a
        0.4 0.4 a
        0.6 0.7 b
        0.65 0.55 b
        0.65 0.55 b
        0.7 0.6 b
        0.75 0.65 b
        0.8 0.75 b
        0.9 0.6 b
        0.7 0.6 b
        0.5 0.7 b
        0.5 0.55 b
        0.6 0.8 b
    };
    \legend{}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{CAP HERE}
\label{statsexample}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why are you asking this here and not on [tex.se]?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a TiKz issue rather than a Latex one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your row separator. You can use `row sep=crcr` instead:

```
\begin{figure}
  \tcbox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend pos=south east,
      xlabel=Variable 1, % label x axis
      ylabel=Variable 2, % label y axis
      ]
      \addplot[
        scatter, only marks,
        scatter/classes={
          a={mark=square*,blue},
          b={mark=triangle*,red}
        }
      ]
      table[x=x,y=y,meta=label,row sep=crcr]{
      x    y    label\\
      0.1  0.35 a\\
      0.2 0.4 a\\
      0.25 0.35 a\\
      0.3 0.4 a\\
      0.3 0.35 a\\
      0.4 0.3 a\\
      0.45 0.3 a\\
      0.4 0.4 a\\
      0.6 0.7 b\\
      0.65 0.55 b\\
      0.65 0.55 b\\
      0.7 0.6 b\\
      0.75 0.65 b\\
      0.8 0.75 b\\
      0.9 0.6 b\\
      0.7 0.6 b\\
      0.5 0.7 b\\
      0.5 0.55 b\\
      0.6 0.8 b\\
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{CAP HERE}
  \label{statsexample}
\end{figure}
```

[image]